# Right way to store encrypted info

Tags: encryption-symmetric

I need to store a sensible info in a database (clients passwords). Is there a common practice? The information should be accessible by various users. Think about service company that should make maintenance of clients systems.

I'm thinking about using AES encryption. All the information is encrypted with the same main key. For every user this main key is encrypted with the user's password used as the key and stored separately. During login and authentication the main key is decrypted and saved in a session. Later the key is used to decrypt clients info. Is it a good practice?

Thanks

P.S.: Yes, I know that it's better not to use passwords, but it's not me to decide the way to access client's servers.

Comment: Good practice - do not store client's passwords. For a service company better to use some other ways for authentication.

Comment: Isn't Blowfish ancient? Use AES or Twofish or something newer.